# HTML code in SharePoint text box to be on right

Tags: html, sharepoint

Hello I have this HTML code from SharePoint.

I want "Titel" (English: "Title") to be on the left and "Textkörper" (English: "text body") to be on the right.

How can I do that?

```html
<tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
       <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
 <nobr>Titel<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
 </nobr>
       </H3>
</td>

<tr>
<td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
       <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
 <nobr>Textkörper</nobr>
 </H3>
</td>
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of HTML to read through! Can you try to reduce it to just the most important parts? (see suggestions for a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) As a bonus, reducing it might help you figure out the answer yourself.

Comment: That's *much* better! :-) Now, try to explain how you have tried to solve the problem, and how you know they didn't work. (Again, this process makes a better question AND might help you figure out the answer yourself!)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to give you help ifyou could be a bit more clear about what *exactly* you want, but I've had a go...

If you mean that you want them to be aligned right and left, perhaps something like this, using `style="text-align: right;` on your `ms-standardheader` h3 tag.

```html
<tr>
  <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
    <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
     <nobr>Titel<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
     </nobr>
           </H3>
  </td>

  <tr>
    <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
      <H3 class="ms-standardheader" style="text-align: right;">
     <nobr>Textkörper</nobr>
     </H3>
    </td>
```

Comment: That is SharePoint form. I need to be first

"Titel" and next to titel "Textkörper"

Comment: Could you give us your whole code, for example on jsfiddle.net? And do you mean you want them side by side? I'm a bit confused as to what exactly you want...